# How to save specific rows of a csv into a new csv using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to filter a CSV based on 'Country Code' and save it into a new CSV.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geo/geotargets-2021-02-24.csv')
df.loc[df['Country Code']=='IN']
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Harshal\Desktop\tar.csv')
```

The `print(df)` is printing the rows where `'Country Code'=='IN'` but the tar.csv file contains the entire data and not the selected rows as CSV.

Comment: You are discarding the result of the filter; you need: `df = df.loc[df['Country Code']=='IN']`.

Comment: Simple, and don't use `.loc`: `df[df['Country Code'] == 'IN'].to_csv(...)`

Comment: @0x5453 Thanks it worked.

Comment: @elPastor Why not use .loc?

Comment: It's not necessary.  `.loc` is typically used if you want to filter by both row and column - but in your example, you didn't want to remove any columns.  When I use `.loc`, I use something like: `df.loc[df['id'] == 'X001', ['timestamp','value']]` and that will give me a new dataframe filtered by `id` but with only the timestamp and value columns.